# Jailbroken iOS Emulator Available?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, jailbreak

Are there any jailbroken iPhone (iOS) emulators available for security research?

I would like to research and experiment with iOS security; however, I don't have jailbroken iPhones with different versions of iOS to play with.

Are there any way to obtain jailbroken iPhone emulators for security research, either from Apple or from public repository?